# knockout select option not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, knockout.js

I am working on a project in which data is fetched from the api and i am trying to make a drop down list, using select binding . I have declared my selected value object observable object in my data model but when i am trying to use the value binding in select option its giving me an error of value is not a function:

```
//....
    <h1 class="page-header">Kitchen</h1>
    <select data-bind="options:dataModel.options()[0]['Kitchen'], optionsText:'label', value: selectedValue">
    </select>
</div>`
```

This is the HTML code where i made select:

```
var dataModel = {
    selectedValue : ko.observable()
};
```

As i said earlier the data is fetched from json file .

This is how json looks like:

```
"options": {
    "Kitchen": [{
        "label": "Ivory",
        "data": "001-001"
    },
    {
        "label": "Chocolate",
        "data": "001-002"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `options` from json is not an array (the array one is the `Kitchen`), so shouldn't it be `dataModel.options()['Kitchen']` instead of `dataModel.options()[0]['Kitchen']`. Or maybe you can put `dataModel.options().Kitchen`
So the `select` is going to be look like:

```
<select data-bind="options:dataModel.options().Kitchen, optionsText:'label', value: selectedValue">
</select>
```

Comment: No its working that ways. I am doing in this dataModel.options()[0]['Kitchen'] way because kitchen is inside options object. Options is the observable array. And Even if you could help me fetching the value of Options and then their specific data like name,data instead of hard wiring them.

Comment: I don't quite get this part: "And Even if you could help me fetching the value of Options and then their specific data like name,data instead of hard wiring them". The goal is to list the `Kitchen's label`  in the dropdown right?

Comment: @RishabhSharma So the `select` is already working, the dropdown list also already shows the correct list, but the selected value gives error when you want to use it?

Comment: I have been able to select the value in the dropdown list but my select function is working one step behind. Example if we select option 1 console.log prints nothing. But if we select option 1 or any option again then it prints the previous value.

Comment: And I was asking image there is Kitchen , flooring , apartment in the options. And I want to fetch the values from each of them like I am doing right now for the kitchen. But right now i am hard wiring the knockout to kitchen only. What if there are many options and I want value from every sub options( Kitchen , floor , rooms ) etc.

Comment: @RishabhSharma If you want every value from every sub options I think you have to map those into a new array variable, and then you put that new array variable in the `<select>`